# Accessing User Password in DNN API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-web-api, dotnetnuke

I am trying to access user's password hash using DNN API. Please see below code segment

```
[AllowAnonymous]
[HttpGet]
public HttpResponseMessage Auth()
{
    UserInfo u = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetUserByName("user1");
    string hostPassword = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.GetPassword(ref u, String.Empty);
    return Request.CreateResponse(HttpStatusCode.OK, hostPassword);
}
```

But I am getting following error, saying hashed passwords can't be retrieved

```
Parser Error Message: Configured settings are invalid: Hashed passwords cannot be retrieved. Either set the password format to different type, or set enablePasswordRetrieval to false.
```

This is my configuration section

```
<add name="AspNetSqlMembershipProvider" type="System.Web.Security.SqlMembershipProvider" connectionStringName="SiteSqlServer" enablePasswordRetrieval="true" enablePasswordReset="true" requiresQuestionAndAnswer="false" minRequiredPasswordLength="7" minRequiredNonalphanumericCharacters="0" requiresUniqueEmail="false" passwordFormat="Hashed" applicationName="DotNetNuke" description="Stores and retrieves membership data from the local Microsoft SQL Server database" />
```

Can anyone explain what is the wrong with my code or configuration.?

Further, If I want to authorize users I would I do it in DNN web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found a reliable way to authenticate users in DNN.
It is possible to authenticate a DNN user in the following way.

```
System.Web.Security.Membership.ValidateUser(username,password)
```

Retrieving hased passwords is not allowed in DNN and it is not a good practice too. That's the reason for the error message for my code.

Comment: what if the asp membership tables are not used? it is not required in DNN you know.

Comment: you should use the DotNetNuke.Security.Membership.MembershipProvider instead

Comment: In earlier versions of DNN I was able look up a user password like this: `  UserInfo u = new UserInfo();
                u = UserController.GetUserById(intPortalID, UserId);
                var p = UserController.GetPassword(ref u, "");`    Happy to see that no longer works.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe a more reliable alternative is to check this within DNN infrastructure:

```
public static bool IsValidUserAndPassword(string username, string password, out UserInfo user)
{
  UserLoginStatus status = UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_FAILURE;
  user = DotNetNuke.Entities.Users.UserController.ValidateUser(PortalSettings.Current.PortalId, username, password, "", PortalSettings.Current.PortalName, HttpContext.Current.Request.UserHostAddress, ref status);
  return user != null && user.UserID != -1 && status == UserLoginStatus.LOGIN_SUCCESS;
}
```

Usage:

```
UserInfo user;
if(IsValidUserAndPassword("username", "password", out user))
{
  // User is valid
  // Do whatever stuff here...
}
```